# Turn off regular expressions in Visual Studio Code Search

Tags: regex, visual-studio-code

Is there a way to turn off regular expressions when searching in VS Code?  Oftentimes, when searching for a specific line of code (or partial line), VS Code interprets the search string as an "Invalid regular expression".  I just want to do a search on a literal string without VS Code attempting to interpret the entry as a regular expression.  I do not see any way to turn this off in the Features / Search options.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Click on the `.*` symbol on the right side of the Find/Search box to disable the regular expression mode. Alternatively hit <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd> when the the Find/Search box is active.

[image: Image showing the Regular Expression mode button.]

The `.*` icon is used more often to represent a regular expression. It is itself a regular expression consisting of `.` meaning any character (except for line terminators) and the `*` quantifier meaning "0 or more occurrences". It effectively means "match anything".

Comment: I never even noticed that.  Thanks.